# Eagle - Export SMD components to inches not mm

Tags: surface-mount, eaglecad

I am trying to export the BOM in a pcb, for use in a pick and place machine.
The way I do this is by clicking on `File -> Export -> Mount SMD`.

This is what the generated `mnb` file looks like.

```
C1 12.45 43.18 270 100n C0805
C2 22.44 61.98 180 100n C0805
C3  0.00 31.24  90 100n C0805
C4  2.03 31.24  90 10u C0805
```

As you can see, the `X` and `Y` coordinates are in mm, while I want the output to be in inches.

Even though the grid is selected to be in inches, the output still remains in mm and I see no option available to change it to inches.

Is there a way to change it to inches?

I am using `Eagle 7.7.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, however it converts to mil.
Find the file `mountsmd_mil.ulp` in your system.

Open it with a text editor. Change all references to `u2mm` to `u2mil`. Save the file.

Now when you do `File -> Export -> MountSMD`, the dimensions will be in mil.

Original reference link located here:
https://community.element14.com/products/eagle/f/eagle-user-support-english/40903/generating-pick-and-place-file-with-mountsmd-ulp